# Case-sensitivity issue in sql import-export wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am importing data using import-export wizard.

but after data get loaded to  table, a unique problem occured.

This value

> http://www.bosecarmfr.com/012re0020
>   got changed  to
>    http://www.bosecarmfr.com/012RE0020

Datatype of column is `VARCHAR (500)`. AND COLLATION is  `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

may anyone please suggest how can we rectify this.

Comment: is there an `ON INSERT` trigger on the destination table? or is it a computed column? otherwise it will be hard to explain why just part of the string was uppercased. -- no, wait... unlikely. the second string differs by more than the case. there is 0020 vs. 0010... not related to the wizard IMO.

Comment: @dlatikay: No Trigger ... some typo error corrected now.

Comment: This is almost certainly not due to the import/export wizard. Copy a row manually (copy-paste from Management Studio) to see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: your collation is case sensitive.

Comment: is there a pattern (always "re" > "RE" capitalization, always the part following the last slash in the string)? custom transformation rules applied in wizard? Are you sure the copy source is a table, not a view, or what is your source, after all?

Comment: @TheGameiswar: case (in)sensitivity of a collation only plays a role in comparisons. It does absolutely nothing to data when stored or retrieved. (The character set of the collation is another matter, but all characters are part of Latin-1.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert:Thanks